# Find all applicable font sizes for a particular font

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I'm looking for a way finding a list of all applicable font sizes for a particular font.  At one time in the past I've learned that not each font looks great at certain sizes, due to the base body size of the font.

So I was wondering if there is some kind of library that can calculate all the applicable sizes something in this way of thinking

```
Font font = new Font("Times New Roman");
List<Integer> fontSizes = font.getApplicableSizes();
```

I'm not sure if it exist but if it does I would like to know, I googled for a while but I might not be searching on the right keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any integer value is a valid size for a [TTF font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType).

> ### History
>
> The system was developed and eventually released as TrueType with the launch of Mac OS System 7 in May 1991. The initial Truetype outline fonts, four-weight families of Times Roman, Helvetica, Courier, and the Pi font replicated the original PostScript fonts of the Apple LaserWriter. Apple also replaced some of their bitmap fonts used by the graphical user-interface of previous Macintosh System versions (including Geneva, Monaco and New York) with scalable Truetype outline-fonts. For compatibility with older systems, Apple shipped these fonts, a TrueType Extension and a TrueType-aware version of Font/DA Mover for System Software 6. For compatibility with the Laserwriter II, Apple developed fonts like ITC Bookman and ITC Chancery in Truetype format.
>
> All of these fonts could now scale to **all sizes on screen and printer,..**

Comment: I guess the best choice would be to support the same sizes that are supported in the office tools.  I had hoped to fetch them from some kind of java Font library, no such luck

Comment: Ehh..  (shrugs)  I'd offer the user any font size between 1 and 300 px in a spinner.  Caveat emptor.  And let's face it, if the user is wasting their time making a 'zoom in' animation of a sign on 300 pages of A-3 paper while bored in the office, that is their bosses concern (OK ..and trees).